What is b-bit precision?
I'm looking at the BitNet paper on 1-bit models by Wang et al.
In section 2.1, they write

We further quantize the activations to b-bit precision

I assume they mean quantize the activations to something less than 8-bit (or 16-bit or 32-bit) precision. Which is it?
I tried googling for "b-bit precision" but people write things like "Activations are quantized to b-bit precision" as if b is a number.

I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide a full citation: paper title, authors, and a link to a freely available PDF.  We have collected some advice here. Thank you!

$b$ is a variable.  If you keep reading a little further, they specify the value of $b$ a few sentences later:

In this work, we quantize the activation to 8-bit and leave lower precision in future work.

In general, when reading a paper, if there is something specific you don't understand, sometimes you can keep a list of those unclear parts but continue reading, and sometimes it will become clear a little later on into the paper (e.g., in the experimental section).
